# What is the difference between occlusion culling and occlusion handling?

Tags: unity-game-engine, augmented-reality, occlusion, occlusion-culling

I've researched the occlusion problem in Augmented reality. I read some academic articles and they categorized them as "Occlusion Handling". Then I googled the same question and I realized people discuss "Occlusion Culling" with some known algorithms which are Z-Buffer, S-Buffer or C-Buffer, BSP, Warnock Algorithm or k-d tree etc.

I am trying to develop an algorithm to solve occlusion problem in Augmented Reality. My question is that is it possible to apply "Occlusion Culling" algorithms to the real scene (Augmented reality) for solving occlusions? Or "Occlusion Handling" and "Occlusion Culling" are the same things under different topics? ?